# MT3608 DC-DC converters in parallel with common output

Tags: circuit-design, dc-dc-converter

I'm thinking to use two DC-DC MT3608 converters in parallel with a single potentiometer.

[image]

Has anyone experience with these converters?, Any advice?.

Thanks

Comment: Any boost converter configuration will suffer from pretty much the same issues, load sharing. Have you googled the subject? Have you looked into droop regulation?

Comment: Consider they have slightly different reference voltages. The high one will supply all the load. The low one will be shut off. Even if you had a pot on each, you'd then have the problem of sharing the output load from two slightly different output voltages. You need a more sophisticated circuit that actively shares the output current to use two. You'd be better off just using one converter that was large enough.

Answer (score 0):

> *Has anyone experience with these converters?, Any advice?*

The MT3608 that naturally produces a few milli volts (or several tens of mV) greater output voltage compared to the other one will win the "diode battle" and supply circa 90% of the load current.

But it gets a little worse. The diode supplying most of the load current will warm up more than the other and its forward voltage will drop hence, the "circa 90%" figure might become circa 95%: -

[image]

Picture from [here](http://www.kennethkuhn.com/students/ee351/diode_characteristics.pdf).

Is this what you want?

By the way, you drew you circuit incorrectly. It should be like this: -

[image]

Comment: Surely it's worse than that? It doesn't get as far as an output diodes problem, it's a feedback problem. You have an output problem if each converter has its own feedback. With shared feedback, the converter that wins will turn the other off.

Comment: @Neil_UK yes, it gets worse.... circa 95% becomes nearly 100%.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use (2) Mt3608 boards, with individual batteries or power supplies, outputing through (2) Diodes to Common Output with a Bypass Cap ?

No feedback or shorts with the Diodes.

[image]

Comment: The battery symbols are incorrectly labeled. Use the CircuitLab schematic editor in the question editor 's toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

From [Neil's comment](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/496742/mt3608-dc-dc-converters-in-parallel-with-common-output/703875#comment1265182_496742):

> Consider they have slightly different reference voltages. The high one will supply all the load. The low one will be shut off. Even if you had a pot on each, you'd then have the problem of sharing the output load from two slightly different output voltages. You need a more sophisticated circuit that actively shares the output current to use two. You'd be better off just using one converter that was large enough.

A common compromise is to add series resistors to the outputs of two regulators, but this isn't applicable to a single-control scenario.  More likely, an active circuit is required to balance them.  In which case you're adding more complexity than simply using a more powerful regulator in the first place; alternately, choose a controller like UC3843 or LM3481 for example, and scale the attached transistor to whatever your application requires.